# Mixing problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A tank contains $70$ kg of salt and $1000$ L of water. A solution of a concentration $0.035$ kg of salt/liter enters a tank at the rate $5$ L/min. The solution is mixed and drains from the tank at the same rate. Find the amount of salt in the tank after $4$ hours.

I know $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = rate in - rate out. The rate in is $0.175$ kg/min; the rate out is $\frac{5x}{1000}$ kg/min.

Setting the equation up, I get
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= 0.175 - \frac{5x}{1000} \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{5}{1000} (35-x) \\
\frac{dx}{35 - x} &= \frac{5}{1000} dt
\end{align*}

Integrating gives
\begin{align*}
-\ln|35-x| &= \frac{5}{1000}t + c \ | \ x(0)=0 \\
35-x &= Ce^{5/1000} \\
C &= 35
\end{align*}
thus 
$$
x(t) = 35 - 35e^{-5t/1000} 
$$
Plugging in $4$ hours $ = 240$ minutes for $t$, I end up with 
\begin{align*}
y &= 35 - 35e^{-1.2} \\
y &= 24.45 \ldots
\end{align*}
I added that to the starting amount and not getting the right answer.

Comment: Yes, please do as the bot says, and format your question with MathJax... as it is now, it is quite hard to read/make sense of.

Comment: @David Your solution is right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is a mistake made in determining the initial condition for the problem. The initial amount of salt in the tank $x(0) = 70$ kg. As a result, the solution to the differential equation is

$x(t) = 35(1 + e^{-0.005t})$,

where $t$ is in minutes.Finally, by plugging $t = 240$, we get

$x(240) = 45.54$ kg.

Hope this helps.